# Are these constellations real?

Tags: pokemon

[image]

Are these poke-constellations real ? If so , then how do the constellations relate to the Pokémon , of vice versa ? And would you also please explain any other information you may have about the constellation and Pokémon relationship ? Or are these constellations just and only in the anime ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, [constellations are a thing in the Pokémon universe](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_constellation).  Well, sort of; they don't really have any lore behind them at all.

> Pokémon constellations appear multiple times in the Pokémon games and anime. Currently, **no star charts or lore exist for constellations in the Pokémon world.**

This brings me to your image; with the exception of Milotic and Gardevoir, **none of those constellations exist in any media related to Pokémon**, according to Bulbapedia.  Pokemon Channel is the only media in which both Milotic and Gardevoir appear as far as games, and in the movie *Jirachi:  Wish Maker*, they are seen as well.

...Also, your particular picture is unofficial art work, so the likelihood of it being canon at all is pretty much nil.